# DolphinDB: How to concatenate streaming data from two rows of the same stock at the same timestamp into a single row?

Tags: streaming, dolphindb

Suppose there is a table t with a “Time“ column, a “StockID“ column, a “tag“ column, and another 50 columns (e.g. F1, F2, F3…F50). For each stock at a specific timestamp, there are two records with tag A and tag B.

I want to convert t to a table with a “Time“ column, a “StockID“ column, and another 100 columns (e.g. F1A, F1B, F2A, F2B…F50A, F50B). How to achieve it in DolphinDB?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `createEquiJoinEngine` function, specify t to both leftTable and rightTable, “Time“ to timeColumn, “StockID“ to matchingColumn, and ingest records with tag A into the left table and records with tag B into the right table of the equi join engine.